# Keep port in url when usung redirect in Zend Framework

Tags: redirect, zend-framework

I have a Windows development machine with an Ubuntu VM set up via vagrant.  The VM has Nginx running on port 80 and the Vagrant configuration maps port 8080 on the host Windows machine to port 80 on the VM.  For various reasons the project that I'm working uses 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost so, in my browser on the Windows machine, I hit a URL such as:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo/bar/baz

The application on the VM is built with Zend Framework 1.12.

If I click a link that has an href="/foo/bar/baz" then all is fine and I go to:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo/bar/baz

However, if in one of my controllers I use a redirect to "/foo/bar/baz" then the browser loads:

http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/baz - i.e without the port in it.

If I then manually edit the URL in the browser's address bar to add the port and hit enter then the page comes up correctly.

I've tried various ways of doing the redirect programatically in ZF, and even tried typing a hard coded URL into the code, but whatever I do it always strips out the port component when the redirect takes place.

Any ideas/suggestions as to how to keep the port in the redirect would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which method are you using to perform the redirect?

Comment: I've tried various methods, the latest was:  
    $redirector = $this->_helper->redirector;  
    $redirector->setUseAbsoluteUri(true);  
    $redirector->gotoUrl('/foobar');

Comment: How about `gotoRoute()` or `gotoSimple()` instead?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, the more I think about it, the more it makes sense that the redirector will ignore the port. After all, the app running in the VM is unaware that you are using a port forward. Hmm...